# Spreadsheets Reduce JS Like Function with 2d range?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, counting

I have this sheet layout:

[image: initial layout]

I would like to place a function on cell A2 and obtain this:

[image: desired result]

The goal is that in the A column obtain the number of B7 occurrences in each row. My Aim is to be able to change the TYPE (B7) and recalculate.

I know this is easy if I place a function in each A2:A6 cell but **I need to be able to compute an array result with a single function on A2** (my calculations are more complicated than the one presented, I'm simplifying it in order to make it as easy as possible).

I've tried to use the following function in A2:

```
=arrayformula(countifs(filter(C2:G6;B2:B6=B2);B$7))
```

With this formula I've tried to filter each row and compute the number of occurrences in each one, but the countifs works on a 2d range and returns a single element as a result (with all occurrences for the first row only)

I also know that I can compute my output using custom JS function but I would like to know if anyone has a solution using native Spreadsheets functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(B2:B6), 
 MMULT(IFERROR(C2:G6=B7, 0)*1, TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(C2:G2)^0)), ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Very clever! I didn't know about the MMULT function. Also +1 for the Transpose trick on cloumn^0, nice!

Comment: Just a question, why the first ```IF(LEN(B2:B6),...)``` check?

Comment: just in case...(on provided example its not needed but your real dataset may look differently to my knowledge). you can remove the IF function completely if you want.